# How can I use an alias name in a SUM Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wasn't sure how to word the question and I know the wording is bad, but the question itself is pretty simple.

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
 SELECT /*stuff*/
      , ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS "c1"
      , SUM(a.x - c1) AS "c2"
 /* more stuff */
```

This is what happens.

**Invalid column name 'c1'.**

I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I can always do it elsewhere in the code, but I try to let the SQL do most of the work for me.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You can not alias a column and use that column in single select

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the alias of another column in the same level of `SELECT`.

You will have to do this -

```
SELECT /*stuff*/
  , ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS "c1"
  , SUM(a.x - ISNULL (a.z, a.y)) AS "c2"
/* more stuff */
```

Also make sure that column `a.z` has only values or `NULL` and column `a.y` has values when `a.z` is `NULL`. By values I mean `Numbers`

Answer (score 5):

You can place the query inside of another query to use the alias

```
SELECT Sum(a.x - c1) as c2
FROM
(
    SELECT /*stuff*/
      , ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS "c1"
     /* more stuff */
) a
```

Or

```
SELECT /*stuff*/
      , ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS "c1"
      , SUM(a.x - ISNULL (a.z, a.y)) AS "c2"
 /* more stuff */
```

Comment: How you will get C1 with sum now.

Comment: @Romil if you get the c1 in the inner query and alias it, then you can use the alias in the outer query

Comment: Now this the answer OP is expecting. +1 for modification.

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to adhere to "don't repeat yourself", I'll propose a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
   select ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS [c1]
   from yourTable
)
select sum([c1])
from cte
```

That way, you don't have to repeat the `ISNULL (a.z, a.y)` bit in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to just combine the functions on one line. If you don't need C1 then just eliminate it as an output.

```
SELECT /*stuff*/
      , ISNULL (a.z, a.y) AS "c1"
      , SUM(a.x - ISNULL(a.z, a.y)) AS "c2"
```